# Element not found selenium web driver issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec

I am using selenium with `rspec` and in the `spec` file i have:

```
wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "data_source_type_name") }
RuleDesc = driver.find_element(:id, "data_source_type_name")
RuleDesc.send_keys "Mobility"
```

and in html i have:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="data_source_type_name" name="data_source_type[name]" required="">
      </div>
```

which is actually under Bootstrap modal(i.e. visible only after a button is clicked) I simulated the click. It shows the modal with that specific div but i get this following error:

```
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20150119-6088-50uggo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8991:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

Edit: when I print the puts `RuleDesc.displayed`? it returns false but in webdriver it is being displayed.

Comment: can you try this, `find(:xpath, "//*[contains(@id, 'data_source_type_name')]")`

Comment: every selector i try returns same except 
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('data_source_type_name').value ='Test value';")
which actually works but i dont want to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well i did some customization,in spec I changed the css of the containing Bootstrap Modal to display:block; using javascript (which was not being triggered by clicking the button, why? dont know, but it was being displayed.) before accessing the elements in that container. Tada, then every selector css,Xpath or ID was smooth as cream.